# How to pass variables to SCSS from a Django View

Tags: django, sass, django-views, scss-mixins

I have a simple problem, but cannot find the literature to find a solution for.  I would like to let the user choose night mode, day mode, vibrant mode, etc. on my Django website. For that to work, I need to pass that variable to my SCSS file.  How do I go about that?  How can I pass a variable from the Django view to a SCSS file?  I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6052381/3549766), but this does not show it by an example and is not about SCSS files.  I'd appreciate if you could provide a short example with your answer as well as the relevant documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

To works with "skins" mode, you must create your css theme files, and rather than pass scss variables you must pass which file your website must import, like

if user choose nightmode, import nightmode.css

if user choose lightmode, import lightmode.css

Comment: This may work.  But, this means that I will have to make different .css files for each "skin".  It just sounds too much work for a simple change.  I understand that you can pass variables from Ruby to Sass/SCSS files, there may be a way to do the same in Django too.

Comment: scss files must be compiled, its not like overide a css file, dats why you cant simples tell do scss file "change the value of this variable" you must have a deploy system to work like this, then when you update your variable, tell to your deploy run a task manager and compile your files.

Comment: So then the question becomes this: is there such a task manager in Python that takes the variable from the user and compiles the SCSS using the new user input?

Comment: Could using this package https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/django-scss and reload your style tag with Ajax on user input be a solution ? Or if you dont need it to be dynamic, I think this package is what you need.