# Jumbotron background image not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I tried a couple of different things and if I manually pug in my photo through my HTML where Jumbotron is, my pictures do load, although with padding which I don't want AND it's not in the background. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. I tried two different ways and neither of those works. The only thing that works is doing `img src=` straight into the Jumbotron section but like I said that's what I want. So what am I doing wrong here?

**project urls**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('dating_app.urls', namespace= 'dating_app')),


] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dating_app/static"),
]
```

**home.html/styles**

```
.JumboHeaderImg{
  background-image: url("/Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/static/images/jumbo.jpg");

}



    .JumboHeaderImg{
  background-image: "{% static 'images/jumbo.jpg' %}";
```

**home.html/jumbotron**

```
 <div class="jumbotron  JumboHeaderImg">
```

**styles.css**

```
.navbar-nav  li{
  padding-left:35px;
  padding-right:10px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;

}

/* Modify the backgorund color */ 
.navbar-custom { 
    background-color: #ffffff; 
} 


.jumbotron{
    background-color: #f76062228c;
}
.navbar .nav-item{
    color: red;
}



.notification {



  text-decoration: none;
  padding:50;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

}



.notification .badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 40%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: where is your style file for home.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052341/using-a-django-variable-in-a-css-file

Comment: there got it up there

Comment: The code is fine from what I can see so you need to debug. Change the image to a 100% working image i.e. http://mywebsite.com/myimage.jpg. Does it work? If so the issue is the server seeing your image link. If not, then you have some CSS overriding the background-img property. Right click on the Jumbotron and Inspect, see what the background-img property is set to

Answer (score 0):

instead of hard coding, static images you have to call this way in django templates

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'images/jumbo.jpg' %}" alt="">
```

in css you can call this way

```
style="background-image: url('{% static "images/jumbo.jpg"%}')";
```

Comment: I tried that already in css, not working though. Already did load static

Comment: make sure you added STATIC_URL = '/static/' in settings file. and this code in main url urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Comment: I just added my settings.py. I believe my STATIC_URL is correct

Comment: And my project urls .

Comment: First off, first version doesn't work And second one isn't formatted correctly , has one missing or one extra quote. Fix that so I can use try it.

Answer (score -1):

is your css file linked to the HTML? if not, then it might be a file path problem

Comment: the Jumbotron code is directly in home.html, at the very top in a <styles> section

Comment: The one 'JumboHeaderImg'

Comment: do you have a closing </div>? try placing the image itself on the same directory as the HTML file so that you can use the path 'jumbo.jpg'

Comment: the image itself works if I do <img src = "{% static 'images/jumbo.jpg' %}"> directly into the html